# use .removeFromThreads in more than 100 threads inside a google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

i have a script that removes every thread within a label and all sublabels.This was workng fine, but recently i got an error that says that the operation `childrens[i].removeFromThreads(threads);` can not be applied to more that 100 threads... How can i fix this?

```
function removingThreadsfromLabel() {
  var parentlabelstring = 'THELabel';
  var parentlabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(parentlabelstring);
  var childrens = children(parentlabel);

  for (var i = 0; i < childrens.length; i++){
    var threads = childrens[i].getThreads();
    childrens[i].removeFromThreads(threads);
  }
}

function children(parent) { 
  var name = parent.getName() + '/';
  return GmailApp.getUserLabels().filter(function(label) {
    return label.getName().slice(0, name.length) == name;
  });
}
```

For now i have done the following, but it is not optimal...

```
function removingThreadsfromLabel() {
  var parentlabelstring = 'THELabel';
  var parentlabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(parentlabelstring);
  var childrens = children(parentlabel);

  for (var i = 0; i < childrens.length; i++){
    var threads = childrens[i].getThreads();
    Logger.log(threads.length);
    while (threads.length>100){
      childrens[i].removeFromThread(threads[0]);
      var threads = childrens[i].getThreads();
    }   
    childrens[i].removeFromThreads(threads);
  }
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i figure out how to do it in batch, so it is better that my first solution:

```
function removingThreadsfromLabel() {
  var batchSize = 100;
  var parentlabelstring = 'THELabel';
  var parentlabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(parentlabelstring);
  var childrens = children(parentlabel);

  for (var i = 0; i < childrens.length; i++){
    var threads = childrens[i].getThreads();
    Logger.log(threads.length);
    for (var j = 0; j < threads.length; j+=batchSize) {
      childrens[i].removeFromThreads(threads.slice(j, j+batchSize));
    }
    var threads = childrens[i].getThreads();
    childrens[i].removeFromThreads(threads);    
  }
```

Comment: Don't you mean splice()? I don't think slice changes the original array. I would have guessed perhaps splice(0,batchsize);